# Why would upload binary file to a DB web server?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm doing a project on SQLNinja for school and in common types of attacks they discuss uploading binary files as seen here in the upload section: http://sqlninja.sourceforge.net/sqlninja-howto.html#ss2.6

I assume this is to gain access to the database or modify it but I would basically like to know how? What would be uploaded to allow a user to proceed with an attack? Or why else would someone upload a file to a server in this way?

Comment: `common types of attacks they discuss uploading binary files` <= Can you provide a reference that states this is a common type of attack or what type of attack they are inferring? A binary file can be anything and there are ways to limit the binary file size in many DBMS's by restricting the columns size in the schema. Although it is not common to store binary in a relational DB it can be done, is supported, and is used.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest cases of identity theft occurred in 2007, when a hacker uploaded a binary to ATM machines, which recorded credit card and debit card numbers. He accomplished the upload using SQL injection.

Read "The Great Cyberheist" (New York Times)
https://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/14/magazine/14Hacker-t.html

Answer (score 0):

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

File upload can allow for attacks from filling up the disk space, to potentially making it easier to execute the binary later through other flaws in the system.

Comment: The key word is **Unrestricted**, and not just File Upload by itself.